# Column behind column highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So just like highcharts have the [basic area](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic) graph i.e. one area graph behind the another I want to have multi column graphs in which one series will be exactly behind the other series and will be visible through some transparency.

Currently highcharts have stacked column graphs but in those [one series is either on the top of other series](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) or [is beside them](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic).

I hope there must be some configuration available for that.

Comment: Not sure but you can try keeping x axis same for every y points

Comment: Apart of stacking, you can also use the [grouping parameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.grouping) which disable paddings between columns and has influence on overlapping.

Comment: Please see the code for the person who asked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148788/display-bar-as-an-arrow-with-highcharts/. They had overlapping columns with transparency in their example, and that code may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it by setting `grouping: false` in the plotOptions.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/r8vaL7p8/

However, this is - generally speaking - a really bad way to show data, that adds unnecessary complexity and obfuscation of the data for the user.

FWIW.